# Matplotlib Figure flickering when updating

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have a plot in a PyQt window that updates every 10 seconds. The problem is that every time it updates the data in the figure there is a flicker which is quite annoying. Is there a way to solve this? See the code I use to draw the plot:

```
def _plot(self):
    self.fig.clear()
    chart1 = self.fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
    chart2 = self.fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
    chart1.grid(True)
    chart2.grid(True)
    chart1.plot(h_headers,reference)

    for row in rows:
        curve = []
        gap_curve = []
        for v in range(len(h_headers)-1):
            curve.append(#SOME NUMBERS#)
        chart1.plot(h_headers, curve)
        chart2.plot(h_headers, gap_curve)

    self.fig.patch.set_visible(False)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

To call the _plot method I use a Thread:

```
loop = True

class DataStream(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while loop:
            window.update_numbers()
            window._plot()
            window.pyqttable.viewport().update()
            time.sleep(5)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Quite a noob here with Matplotlib, thanks!

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi eyllanesc, I tried to complete a bit more of the code but putting it all would be a mess for any reader as there are too many non-relevant functions linked between each other. I think the blinking or flickering problem comes down to the _plot() method I created although I also think is a normal behavior of matplotlib but there must be a way of avoiding this. Maybe using FuncAnimation? Thanks!

Comment: The problem can be given for n reasons, with the code that samples would not try or give possible causes, if your code has irrelevant things then remove them, that is, create a decent [mcve]. An MCVE must be complete and yours is not.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is having the same problem as me, I just changed

```
self.canvas.draw()
```

to

```
self.canvas.draw_idle()
```

Comment: Having the same problem, but I am not using `canvas` to draw and instead using `plt.show`. I tried adding `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` but it doesn't seem to be working. It is quite annoying (the flicker).

Comment: I'm having this problem too, only I'm using set_data() to update the lines in my plots. Using canvas.draw_idle() didn't work for me either. Does anyone know of any other ways to fix this? I don't think using FuncAnimation will work because I want to control when the plot updates are made.